# Applescript and setting checkbox variable

Tags: checkbox, applescript

I'm incredibly new to coding and the like, and I've started with applescript as it is relatively easy to learn. I'm building a simple gui tool with the help of Pashua and some sample code.

I have added following code for a checkbox:

```
urgent.type = checkbox
urgent.lable = Urgent
urgent.default =
```

I tested it with a simple if then return statement:

```
if urgent is 1 then
   return "This is urgent!"
end if
```

But I'm told that the variable `urgent`is undefined.

I know I am missing something, but I am not sure what to do, and I've looked to no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like JavaScript.  If you want to use AppleScript, then it would be more like this:

```
set urgent to {type:"checkbox", lable:"urgent", default:1}

if (default of urgent) = 1 then
    display dialog "This is urgent!"
end if
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide for record](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDGEAH)